# Why aren't my associations displayed in my records?

Tags: hubspot-crm

I wrote a python code for my hubspot software and it does not work as expected.
I have an original deal (original_deal_id) and a therefrom created deal (hs_object_id).
Now I want to associate the original deal with "maincourse" and the new deal with "precourse".

I've tried this code but the associations are not displayed

```
# create new "precourse" (id 32) and "maincourse" (id 33) user-defined associations if not already exists
import requests
import json
import time
def main(event):
    token = 'pat-na1-d8c379bb-9789-4083-a0a9-d4fb8383c806'
    base_url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v4'
    sleeptime = 2  # wait time in seconds if API request limit reached
    hs_object_id = event.get('inputFields').get('hs_object_id')  # ID of the new deal
    original_deal_id = event.get('inputFields').get('original_deal_id')  # ID of the main deal
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json'
    }
    
    # Modify payload to include "precourse" association
    precourse_payload = [{'associationCategory': 'USER_DEFINED', 'associationTypeId': 32}]  # precourse

    # Replace X with the actual association type ID for "maincourse"
    maincourse_payload = [{'associationCategory': 'USER_DEFINED', 'associationTypeId': 33}]  # maincourse

    try:
        # Associate "precourse" label with the new deal
        status_code = 429
        while status_code == 429:  # code 429 == API request limit reached
            req = requests.put(
                url=f'{base_url}/objects/deal/{hs_object_id}/associations/deal/{original_deal_id}',
                data=json.dumps(precourse_payload),
                headers=headers
            )
            status_code = req.status_code
            if status_code == 429:
                time.sleep(sleeptime)  # short wait time and then request again
        if status_code == 201:
            print(f'Successfully associated with "precourse" label.')
        else:
            print(f'Failed to associate with "precourse" label. Status code: {status_code}. Response: {req.text}')

        # Associate "maincourse" label with the original deal
        status_code = 429
        while status_code == 429:  # code 429 == API request limit reached
            req = requests.put(
                url=f'{base_url}/objects/deal/{original_deal_id}/associations/deal/{hs_object_id}',
                data=json.dumps(maincourse_payload),
                headers=headers
            )
            status_code = req.status_code
            if status_code == 429:
                time.sleep(sleeptime)  # short wait time and then request again
        if status_code == 201:
            print(f'Successfully associated with "maincourse" label.')
        else:
            print(f'Failed to associate with "maincourse" label. Status code: {status_code}. Response: {req.text}')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Exception when processing deals: {e}')
 return {}
```